# Issue with StringEscapeUtils call and JSP form submit value

Tags: java, jsp, xss, stringescapeutils

I am passing some param with value from my JSP file and before that I am using Apache `StringEscapeUtils` to avoid any XSS attack script execution using param value

for example, if somebody inserting value like this and gain access

Cross script test is currently failing when something like this is passed as value

```
site_locale=en_US%2F%3E%3Ciframe+src%3Djavascript%3Aalert%28116%29+
```

Blind SQL Injection test is currently failing when something like this is passed

```
isMgr=true%27+and+%27f%27%3D%27f%27%29+--+
```

My question here is whether `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml` will save from above type of param value passed or do i need any other library

I also wanted to confirm if the way I am calling `StringEscapeUtils` in JSP is correct or not

```
<input type="hidden" name="site_locale" value= <%= StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(site_locale) %> >
```

Appreciate any pointers here

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Utility class for HTML form encoding

```
URLEncoder.encode(yoururlhere, "UTF-8")
```

Similar way, we have

```
java.net.URLDecoder.decode(yoururlhere, "UTF-8");
```